# Are LoadLibrary, FreeLibrary and GetModuleHandle Win32 functions thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi

I'm working on a web service that interacts with a native DLL and I use LoadLibrary/GetModuleHandle/FreeLIbrary and GetProcAddress to dynamically load/unload the DLL because it is not very stable.

```
public class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string libname);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName); 
}
```

I've noticed that w3wp.exe process occationally crashes under heavy load and when I tried to debug it the debugger often stops at my NativeMethods.GetModuleHandle() function call.

I couldn't find any evidence that `GetModuleHandle` is not thread-safe so I'm wondering has anyone got any similar experience when interacting these kernel32.dll function from multi-threaded .NET applications?

Oscar

Comment: LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary should be thread safe relative to the DLL load list, and in theory so should GetModuleHandle, however I would probably use a LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary pair instead of using that method as then you ensure you have a reference to the library and it cannot just vanish from memory while you are using it.

Answer (score 7):

According to Igor Tandetnik (Microsoft MVP).

Aside from GDI functions which are not thread-safe. Almost anything that takes an `HWND` and/or an `HDC` must be  called on the same thread where that `HWND` or `HDC` was created  (`SendMessage`, `PostMessage` and similar are notable exceptions). `HBITMAP`s,  `HICON`s and such could be passed between threads, but should be  manipulated by one thread at a time.

Most other functions - those that don't deal with GDI or window  management - are indeed thread-safe.

This should include `LoadLibrary`, `GetModuleHandle`, `FreeLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Keep in mind however that **`FreeLibrary` should not be called from DllMain**.

I can also add that I have been using these functions in a multi-threaded environment for quite some time without issue.

Comment: https://mvp.support.microsoft.com/profile=b3eb0170-44f2-4819-b048-8616caa4d107 / http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/igor%20tandetnik/?ws=usercard-mini (If this is the correct person) does not work for MS? but he is a MVP...

Comment: Changed answer to reflect previous comment

Comment: Be aware that `LoadLibrary` increments the module's reference count, whereas `GetModuleHandle` does NOT increment the module's reference count.  Sadly, this makes `GetModuleHandle` not thread safe.  See **Remarks** section for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx  Key Note: **For example, suppose that a thread retrieves a module handle, but before it uses the handle, a second thread frees the module. ....**